# How to load class in system level from bootstrap level

Tags: java, classloader, bootstrapping

I have a class that i defined in system.jar and i loaded it from classpatch. But in bootstrap.jar which i put in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext. I need to load a class which was defined in system.jar. How can i load it?

I known. When Tomcat is started, it creates a set of class loaders that are organized into the following parent-child relationships, where the parent class loader is above the child class loader:

```
  Bootstrap
      |
   System
      |
   Common
   /     \
```

Webapp1   Webapp2 ...

No have ways to load class with my idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The class loader hierarchy is `Bootstrap Loader → Extension Loader → Application Loader`.

And, despite it’s name, [`ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader()) will return the application loader which will be the one which resolves classes using the supplied user `CLASSPATH`.

So from a class contained in `bootstrap.jar` (which will be loaded by the *extension loader* when placed in `jre/lib/ext`) you can use `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() .loadClass("class.within.your.classpath")` to load the class from `system.jar`.

As a side note, in this typical setup, the expression `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent()==MyClass.class.getClassLoader()` will evaluate to `true` if `MyClass` has been loader by the extension loader.